There is no variable in Python locals that is defined after executing exec
I am using Python 3.11.9.
Why is there no result variable in the second output? I expected the same result as after executing the first function.
def foo():
    exec('a = 10; b = 5; result = a * b')
    return locals()

def bar():
    exec('a = 10; b = 5; result = a * b')
    return locals()
    result = 100


print(foo()) # {'a': 10, 'b': 5, 'result': 50}
print(bar()) # {'a': 10, 'b': 5}


This is probably answered somewhere in this question

@chepner documentations for exec says "In all cases, if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed in the current scope". Even though the definition of the result variable can't be reached, it has some side effects that I can't understand.
@Barmar it might be explained there, but I would like to read an exact explanation related to my question.

Gah, it's when only a global namespace is passed that it's used for the local scope as well. I always get that wrong.

I think the idea that the code is executed "in the current scope" applies to name lookups, not assignments. The accepted answer to the question Barmar linked to also quotes: "The default locals act as described for function locals() below: modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit locals dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on locals after function exec() returns." So the assignment result = a * b is not equivalent to the assignment result = 100; the object used by exec is not the same as the object returned by locals.

Local namespaces are not just dict objects in the same way the global namespace is.

@Daniil It's effectively the same question. The only differences are that it's asking "how to" and you're asking "why", but the explanation is still the same; and its code is different so the symptom is different. Namely, in your code, where you're trying to modify locals(), you're getting undefined behaviour.

I haven't figured out the exact mechanism, but I realized that the magic happens at the compilation/optimization stage, not at code execution. This question helped a bit.
